# directly writing on file which is on my local machine's directory through extjs application, without using server?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

Is is possible to write on (text/json) file present on local machine using ext js application without using any server ?

Comment: It would be something if that was possible, won't it?

Comment: but from javascript it is possible ???

Answer (score 0):

Please check this links before try:  http://davidwalsh.name/download-attribute
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/#toc-file-writing

```
           {
                xtype: 'button',
                text: 'Save As Txt',
                handler: function() {
                    var me = this;
                    function cleanBlobURL(blobURL) {
                       // Need a some delay for the revokeObjectURL to work properly.
                       setTimeout(function() {
                         window.URL.revokeObjectURL(blobURL);
                       }, 10000);
                    }
                    var link = me.getEl().dom;
                    var data = 'Hello world';
                    var blob = new Blob([data], {type: 'text/plain'});
                    window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
                    var blobURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                    link.href = blobURL; 
                    link.download = 'HelloWorld.txt';
                    cleanBlobURL(blobURL);
                }
            }
```